# Sort array of strings based on matching words with input string

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I was not able to find any solution for below problem in a coding contest.

Problem:
    We have input string of "good words" separated by underscore and list of user reviews (basically array of strings where each array element is having some words separated by underscore).
    We have to sort the list of user reviews such that elements having more number of good words comes first.

```
Example:

input:

good words: "pool_clean_food".

user review array:["food_bedroom_environment","view_sea_desert","clean_pool_table"].

output: [2,0,1]

Explanation:

Array[2]="clean_pool_table" having 2 good words i.e. pool and clean
Array[0]="food_bedroom_environment" having 1 good word i.e. food
Array[1]="view_sea_desert" having 0 good word i.e. nil

How can I approach the problem, which data structure shall I use so that my code can handle large inputs?
```

Comment: Which contest is it? Is the contest ongoing? Its considered as cheating to ask for help during contest

Comment: It has been ended. It was on InterviewBit.com

Answer (score 0):

- Split the words of input *good words* by underscore and store them in a hashset.
- Now for each review, assign score 0 initially. split the words by underscore as well and check if the words are present in the hashset one by one. If the word is present, add 1 to score of that word.
- Now consider every reviews as `<review, score>` pair and sort those reviews based on their score value in ascending order. You can use any standard sorting `O(nlogn)` algorithm for this.

Instead of hashset, you can use Trie which will be speed up the algorithm in case the words are too big.

Comment: But, splitting and iterating each review word by word in a loop will take O(n*n)? Is not there more efficient solution?

Comment: Its `O(n * m)` where `n` is the number of reviews and `m` is each word's length. AFAIK there is no faster way because at least you have to scan each word of each review.